# Нужно сделать круглую рамку PHP

Tags: php

Имеется функция, которая получает из аргументов два URL-a - входной и выходной.
Также она получает толщину и цвет рамки.
Задача: добавить рамку и сделать изображение круглым.
Вопрос: как сделать рамку на круглое изображение?

```
<?php 
function img_circle($file_name = false, $param = 50){
    $err = true;
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file_name);
    $cfg = getimagesize($file_name);
    $width=$cfg[0];
    $height=$cfg[1];

    if($image){
        $err = false;
    }

    if(!$err){

    $x=$width ;
    $y=$height;
    $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($x, $y);
    $bg = imagecolorallocate($img2, 255, 255, 255);
    imagefill($img2, 0, 0, $bg);
    $e = imagecolorallocate($img2, 0, 0, 0);
    $r = $x <= $y ? $x : $y;

    imagefilledellipse($img2, ($x/2), ($y/2), $r, $r, $e);
    imagecolortransparent($img2, $e);
    imagecopymerge($image, $img2, 0, 0, 0, 0, $x, $y, 100);

    imagecolortransparent($image, $bg);

    $W=$cfg[0];
    $H=$cfg[1];

    $img3=imagecreatetruecolor($W/2,$H/2);
    imagecolortransparent($img3, $bg);

    imagecopyresampled($img3,$image,0,0,0,0,$W/2,$H/2,$W,$H);
    $cfg = getimagesize($file_name);
    imagepng($image, $file_name);
    imagedestroy($img2);
    imagedestroy($img3);
    imagedestroy($image);
}}


function change_photo($input_url, $color, $thickness, $output_url){
    img_circle('logo.jpg', 50);
}

change_photo("logo.jpg", "255, 0, 0", 5, "res.jpg");
?>
```

Comment: А с чем проблемы. Вы не знаете как рисовать круг? Вы не знаете как его закрашивать?